# how to select specific one from child array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, ngfor

When i am selecting first parent children array of first then it is selecting every other parent children. I know this is because of index 0 remains to same to everyone. how can i select specific one from children and highlight it.

Link: 
[stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vemdhe)

I have tried comparing index of parent and children but even with that i am not able to select specific one of children array.

home.html

```
<style>
  .highlight {
    background-color:#777;
  }
</style>

<ion-item *ngFor="let date of testList"> 
    {{date.date}} 
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of date.item; let i= index" [class.highlight]="i == selectedOne" (tap)="onSelected(i)">
           {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item>
```

home.ts

```
  public testList: any[] = [
    {
      date: 'test1',
      item: [ {
        name:'tony',
        id:23
      },
       {
         name:'shawn',
         id:12
       },
       {
         name:'rancho',
         id:33
       }
      ]
    },
{
      date: 'test2',
      item: [ {
        name:'Monty',
        id:345
      },
       {
         name:'Bob',
         id:321
       },
       {
         name:'Dexter',
         id:324
       }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: 'test3',
      item: [ {
        name:'Trillo',
        id:234
      },
       {
         name:'Stenly',
         id:12
       },
       {
         name:'Destro',
         id:123
       }
      ]
    }
  ]

  public selectedOne: boolean 
  onSelected(index) {
     if (this.selectedOne != index) {
          this.selectedOne = index;
        } else {
          this.selectedOne = null;
        }
  }
```

i want to select specific one and highlight it.[image]

Comment: Can we select based on text instead of index?

Comment: Can we modify the array of objects that you provided?

Comment: Hey Asim, Name and id will be dynamic, That i am going to get it from backend. Yes we can but it should show like a pic, parent then its children element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nested-loop-styling)

**Your `home.html` like below:~**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<style>
    .highlight {
        background-color: #777;
    }
</style>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let date of testList">
        {{date.date}}
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of date.item; let i= index" [class.highlight]="item.id == selectedOne" (tap)="onSelected(item)">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

**Your `home.ts` onSelected method like below:~**

```
  onSelected(item) {
    this.selectedOne = item.id;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would start by adding a selected attribute to each item shown in the list, you could do this with the following all though I would move this to `ngOnInit()`.

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.testList.forEach(data => data.item.forEach(each => 
        {
          each.selected = false;
        })
     )
  }
```

That would mean you can store against each object whether it has been selected or not. Then would amend your html to look like the following. Changes being, on click you pass through the item and its parent rather than the index and `[class.highlight]` checks against `selected` being `true` or `false`.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let date of testList"> 
    {{date.date}} 
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of date.item; let i= index" 
        [class.highlight]="item.selected" (tap)="onSelected(item, date)">
           {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And make a slight alteration to the function you call on click, this will set `selected` true if it comes in `false` and the opposite.

**Edit**

Define a clear function to clear all, same as the first bit iterating to all being false.

---

```
onSelected(item, parent)
{ 
    this.testList.forEach(data => data.item.forEach(each =>
        { each.selected = false; }));

    item.selected ? item.selected = false : item.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey dince12, Your code works as expected but now when i am selecting parent of children then after that second children it is not removing first children highlight, Even if i am selecting different parent children. is there any way to remove the highlight when i am selecting other children

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check for that made an edit and checked it works

Comment: Hey Dince12. This is getting very close, but still i am able to select every other children and make it highlight, if i am selected first parent children then went to second parent children then highlight should be removed from first parent children. Thank you so much

Comment: ahhh i see what at a time I though one for each no worries last edit coming up :-)

Comment: Hey Dince12, This works reset the whole array, onSelected(item, parent) {
   this.testList.forEach(data =>
        data.item.forEach(each => 
        {
          each.selected = false;
        })
     )
  item.selected ? item.selected = false : item.selected = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

Change the selectedOne variable to Object

```
public selectedOne = {id: 12, name: 'Stenly'};
```

And update condition in loop `[class.highlight]="(item.id == selectedOne.id && item.name == selectedOne.name)"`

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of date.item; let i= index" [class.highlight]="(item.id == selectedOne.id && item.name == selectedOne.name)" (tap)="onSelected(i)">
           {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-one

Comment: This will be static what if i am getting different id and name everytime so it fails class.highlight condition, This wont work with other id and name

Comment: where do you want to dynamic the object?